# When to call a super-class' method?

Tags: python, overriding

I'm working on extending a project maintained by a group of developers. My code involves overriding of methods in the classes from existing code. One of the points of discomfort to me is that I don't know how exactly to override super-class methods.

Below is the description:

```
def foo(self):
    return self.something
```

When I extend this, should I generally try to:

**(1)**

```
def foo(self):
    old_something = super(Sub, self).foo()
    # my code
    return old_something
```

or

**(2)**

```
def foo(self):
    # my code
    return super(Sub, self).foo()
```

I'm sure there's no universal answer, but what is the default? For example, in CL, if you don't specify this behaviour, the default qualifier in method combination is `:around`, meaning case **(2)**. But, in Java, for example, the convention is to call super on the very first line of the method that overrides it, i.e. case **(1)**. What is the Python way to do it?

EDIT:

If I do:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs grep '= super' | wc -l
```

on the project I work on, I get more hits, then if I do:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs grep 'return super' | wc -l
```

Just out of curiosity. Does this hold for some of you / most of you? :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not about convention, it's about what's *correct*. You need to look at what the method you're overriding does, and what its contract is, and write code that does the right thing. Doing a "before" (superclass call at the end of the method), or an "after" (superclass call at the beginning), or an "around" (superclass call somewhere in the middle), or an "override" (no superclass call at all) can *all* be correct depending on the semantics of the method.

Of course, sometimes it really doesn't matter; the code will function just as well with multiple options. In that case, I would lean towards "after" (superclass call first, then your own code), because it aids debugging to have the operations happen in order from generic to specific.

Answer (score 0):

If the method you're overwriting modifies the class in any way, and you're depending on those changes, refer to the first method, so that the method's logic can affect the class in any way it was originally intended to.

If your logic is completely apart from anything the method might have affected in the parent class, then use the second method. It's really a matter of order of operations, and whether or not the super()ed method does anything to the class, that you are dependent on in order to solve the real problem at hand